# Has a player ever rallied from 2 sets down, 0-5 in 3rd set, 0-40 in 6th game?

Tags: trivia, tennis

Has there ever been a professional tennis match where one player lost the first 2 sets, lost the first 5 games of the third set, and was trailing 0-40 in the 6th game of the third set before rallying to win the match?

Comment: I think i've seen a question of this type here already.

Comment: @KharoBangdo I searched and couldn't find this question.

Comment: Sorry, i confused it with "Has there been a tennis match where every set was won to love" question

Comment: You may have a look at: [The highest deficit in a come back](http://tt.tennis-warehouse.com/showthread.php?t=156262) and [Biggest choke from a winning position](http://tt.tennis-warehouse.com/showthread.php?t=424724) at Talk Tennis.

Comment: Saying that it is already 0-2 restrict this to Grand Slams and Davis Cup. (And only men competitions.)

Comment: [winning set after being down 0-5](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=332353)  and [Biggest Chokes of 2012?](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=212622) at menstennisforums. Anyway, I did not find a situation which you described in those threads.